# Is there any way to show annotations of pdftron package using another apps

Tags: flutter, pdf, annotations, pdf-viewer, pdftron

[here we highlight the first paragraph and the secondone but only the second one that appears that is exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RcLy.jpg)we are doing a pdf viewer project using flutter and  we are using pdftron package for this task , and our problem is when we trying to open the pdf file using another application after we did in it some annotations, the annotations don't appears at all
is that because the xfdf format that cannot reach it or why and how we can fix this problem?

we tried another package called pspdf and have the same problem but using jason format and also it doesn't work

Comment: thank you for your answer https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RcLy.jpg @KJ

Comment: I cannot recognize anything on that screenshot...

Comment: PDFTron saves annotations in the PDF in conformance with the PDF ISO standard, so any other conforming PDF reader should display the annotations fine. To help diagnose the issue further, can you please provide your steps/code. Also when you say "using another application" can you please provide a specific example? Finally, if you can post the PDF in question that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

PDFTron uses Collaborative permissions here Justin's Highlights are not seen by Sally

[image]

However Justin can switch on Sally's edits.

[image]

But when Sally saves her comments Justin's are not included for other editors to see. **They are there** just not saved as visible ! **Here in Sally's copy is Justin's comment**

```
/Highlight/T(Justin)/TrnCustomData({"trn-annot-preview":"Another mistake is where organizations select a\\nbasic library to save money with the assumption\\nthat they can build anything needed on top."})/Type/Annot>>
```

[image]

But if Justin saves everybody's they are all there to be seen !

[image]

Since this is a behaviour controlled by PDFTron you need to raise Application User issues with Apryse support.

Whilst Multi-level permissions look good as a concept they are more often a fail than a ONLY 2 Tier system (where there are writer users and reader users, as the comments are tagged as to Author) thus less points of failure in a well managed Document Management System.

You need a user editor that shows hidden comments
[image]